# C# - using library error

Tags: c#, dll

I have a `.dll` file which is in another folder from where my project is. I add the reference to this library into my project and then when I try to use(import) it `using QRlib;` I get the following: `The type or namespace name 'QRlib' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I was given the library file, so it's not me who implemented it, but I have to use it (and I am pretty sure there are no problems with it). What might be the problem ?

Comment: have you changed from release to debug? (or vice versa), chances are its not finding the reference path (right click the reference and look at the path)

Comment: may be namespace QRLib is not correct and something else..

Comment: I didn't get a whole project, but simply the `.dll` file itself so I don't have the _release_ and the _debug_ folders, in order to change between them.

Comment: check the reference path :\, your own project has release and debug

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. is this what your trying to use? http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ (first google search for qrlib)

Answer (score 1):

In solution explorer window of visual studio, expand nodes like this

```
project node=>"reference" node
```

Double click the dll name you added. This will open the object browser window where you will find all namespaces, class and methods.

Comment: yeah, I can see that and I see the project itself, its namespace and the classes in it, but I can't see anything related to the library...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the lib in decompiler (dotPeek for example) and check what are the namespaces. Maybe you are using wrong namespace?

Comment: double clicking the reference in visual studio can show the name spaces (and methods)

Comment: okey, I saw the namespace is `dk.ms_it` in the code of the `.dll` file, how can I relate to that ? I can't use `using dk.....`

Comment: upload the library somwhere if you can and I'll take a look